# Utf-8 to URI percent encoding

Tags: c++, utf-8

I'm trying to convert Unicode code points to percent encoded UTF-8 code units.

The Unicode -> UTF-8 conversion seems to be working correctly as shown by some testing with Hindi and Chinese characters which show up correctly in Notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding, and can be translated back properly.

I thought the percent encoding would be as simple as adding '%' in front of each UTF-8 code unit, but that doesn't quite work. Rather than the expected **%E5%84%A3**, I'm seeing **%xE5%x84%xA3** (for the unicode U+5123).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Added code (note that utf8.h belongs to the UTF8-CPP library).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "utf8.h"

std::string unicode_to_utf8_units(int32_t unicode)
{
    unsigned char u[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    unsigned char *iter = u, *limit = utf8::append(unicode, u);
    std::string s;
    for (; iter != limit; ++iter) {
        s.push_back(*iter);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    if (!ofs.good()) {
        std::cout << "ofstream encountered a problem." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    utf8::uint32_t unicode = 0x5123;
    auto s = unicode_to_utf8_units(unicode);
    for (auto &c : s) {
        ofs << "%" << c;
    }

    ofs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually encode the code units using the characters 0-9 and A-F? Simply adding a percent sign before any random code unit doesn't do percent-escaping.

Comment: It isn't clear why your code generates the "x".  We can't see it.

Comment: @not-rightfold I'm using the utf8cpp library for the unicode -> utf8 conversion, and as far as I can tell, it's working correctly.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Not showing us the code the produces the error. How on earth do you expect us to tell you what's wrong with your code when we can't see it?

Comment: @HansPassant: as far as I can tell, the `xE5` is an artifact. This is the way that Notepad++ represents a non-printable character. The problem is that the OP is just putting `%` before a binary value, without hex-encoding that binary value itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to convert byte values to the corresponding ASCII strings, for example:

`"é"` in UTF-8 is the value `{ 0xc3, 0xa9 }`. Please not that these are bytes, `char` values in C++.

Each byte needs to be converted to: `"%C3"` and `"%C9"` respectively.

The best way to do so is to use [sstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/sstream):

```
std::ostringstream out;
std::string utf8str = "\xE5\x84\xA3";

for (int i = 0; i < utf8str.length(); ++i) {
    out << '%' << std::hex << std::uppercase << (int)(unsigned char)utf8str[i];
}
```

Or in C++11:

```
for (auto c: utf8str) {
    out << '%' << std::hex << std::uppercase << (int)(unsigned char)c;
}
```

Please note that the bytes need to be cast to `int`, because else the `<<` operator will use the litteral binary value.
First casting to `unsigned char` is needed because otherwise, the sign bit will propagate to the `int` value, causing output of negative values like `FFFFFFE5`.

Comment: Your code gives me the result 0x28fd6c when writing out into an output file stream.